# android DialogFragment onKeyUp onKeyDown from onKey

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-keypad

How to mesure how long ex. volume up key has been pressed in DialogFragment?

Unfortunately `DialogFragment` doesn't have methods `onKeyUp, onKeyDown`. :((

So who (which object) receives by default information about pressed keys?

I've learnt that I can use `getDialog().setOnKeyListener(this)` assuming that my class implements `OnKeyListener`.

Great but then I have the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
}
```

But I need `onKeyDown, onKeyUp` (with possibility to call `event.startTracking()`

How to achieve this? How to mesure how long ex. volume up key has been pressed (in `DialogFragment`)?

Comment: onKey() we get the KeyEvent. Using this you can check if the event is action_up or down and start the task that you want to do.  Here is the link for your reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: ok, but I don't have the smallest idea how to do event.startTracking() in that case....?

Comment: Hope this post would be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226771/how-to-differentiate-between-long-key-press-and-regular-key-press

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (arg2.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
        // Key up event
     }
     else{
     // Key down event
     }   

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the onKey callback method inDialogFragment? Though this line was helpful.