# androidTv press home screen and restart

Tags: android, android-tv

I am making an app to detect home key of d-pad but unfortunately there is no key provided by amazon but I tried another way by using

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    Log.e("Trend Activity", "Home Key pressed");
    finishAffinity();
    Log.e("Trend Activity", "Home Key pressed");
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

but still I am getting issue when pressing long home key of d-pad. It is killing all activity it is good but I don't want to kill activity on long press.
Please help me thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - it is bad practice to override the functionality of the Home key.

However if you really want to do it you will want to look for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME`.

Then check this answer out for differentiating different press types -> [How to differentiate between long key press and regular key press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226771/how-to-differentiate-between-long-key-press-and-regular-key-press)